# Is there an open source depository of custom classes for the Iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm trying to learn Objective-C for xcode.
I was wondering if there was an open source depository for custom classes.
Things that programmers re-use.
( ie. playing card class, or peer to peer methods )

I've searched google, but so far haven't seen any type of site.

Comment: I would be very interested in this myself.  I would love to see a site like codeproject.com for iPhone/iPad stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, search github.

- http://github.com/facebook/three20
- http://github.com/ldandersen/scifihifi-iphone
- http://github.com/clarkware/iphone-goodies
- http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary#readme

The Three20 codebase is very solid.

Comment: Are you sure the current three20 code base is safe for app store submission?  Last I saw they still had not got rid of the private API's.

Comment: No, I'm not sure. But it is open-source ;)

Answer (score 2):

*Shameless plug*

> CocoaPods manages library dependencies for your Xcode project.
>
> You specify the dependencies for your project in one easy text file. CocoaPods resolves dependencies between libraries, fetches source code for the dependencies, and creates and maintains an Xcode workspace to build your project.
>
> Ultimately, the goal is to improve discoverability of, and engagement in, third party open-source libraries, by creating a more centralized ecosystem.

- The tool: https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods
- And the available libraries: https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs

Answer (score 1):

This sort of stuff is typically very dispersed across the web - as suggested in another answer, http://www.github.com is a good resource. Other places to search are -

http://sourceforge.net/search/?type_of_search=soft&words=iphone
http://code.google.com/query/#q=iphone

I keep some examples checked in to Google code under BSD license.  Github and Google Code are good places to contribute any "generic" code you've written back to the community.

Answer (score 0):

if you're interested in developing 2D games, I would definitely check out cocos2D for iPhone. They have a great project which seems to be really taking off.

Comment: Thanks, actually at this point in time I would Point people to Kobold2d instead.

Answer (score 0):

just use github.com and most of the famous libraries are on google codes